# How can I install cv2?

Tags: python, anaconda

My environment:
[Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) LTS (Bionic Beaver) (also tried on [Ubuntu 19.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_19.04_(Disco_Dingo)) (Disco Dingo))

I use/need Python 3 (3.6.8 installed).

I need cv2, which is a model of [OpenCV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV).

I tried several receipts I found on the Internet, but nothing worked.

I tried to install as pre-compiled (`sudo apt-get install python-opencv`) - No error, but when I try the test:

```
import cv2 as cv
print(cv.__version__)
```

I get error *"module not found"*.

The problem seems that I have also installed [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)). The above test then uses Anaconda, and cannot find the module.

Compiling from source installed for Python 2, but I do need Python 3. (The test also uses Anaconda.)

One of my receipts worked till the end, but with the line:

```
workon OpenCV-master-py3
```

It gave me the error "workon not found".

I tried then to install via Conda, but that wants to downgrade Conda.

Is there a way to run it without Anaconda and find a replacement for "workon OpenCV-master-py3"?

Comment: did you try to use `pip3.6` to install it ?

Comment: If it helps someone: On top of `pip3 install opencv-python` I also needed to run `pip install --upgrade numpy`. In full disclosure, in between these two commands in the Ubuntu prompt, I had also run: `git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git` and `pip install regex`, which hadn't solved my problem.

Answer (score 58):

For Python 3 you can simply do `pip3 install opencv-python` and it will work.

Comment: no worries, please mark as correct :) good luck with your work!

Comment: I did the same on another machine and get after "import cv2" No module named 'cv2' -- What do I miss?

Comment: if thats the case, check if the environment is correct. The paths lead to the appropriate location

Comment: How to check that? Just type $PATH

Comment: Its different path on these two machines. Which one is missing, where is the model opencv?

Comment: if youre not using a virtual environment - it should be where your python is installed. If both your machines run the same OS then adjust the path to the one that works. If you are using a virtual env, then the path should point to the virtual environment dirs.

Comment: If I use the virtual environment and I use the command 'pip3 install opencv-python' then this module should be reachable within this environment. However, ipython starts with python 2.7.15 on that machine. On the other machine it starts with Python 3.6.8

Comment: there you go, its looking within your python2.7 installation for that package. You need to point your path to the Python3 installation dirs.

Comment: I copied the exact path from the other machine, Now ipython starts with Python 3.7.3 but still no module cv2

Comment: I got it to work: "conda deactivation" then copy the path and now it works. Need to figure out why it happened and how to avoid. THANKS!

Answer (score 7):

Using `workon`, creating a virtual environment:

`mkvirtualenv -p python3 opencv`

Inside the virtual environment.
If you are only working with images

`pip install opencv-python`

[opencv-python](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/)

If you need support for working videos:

`pip install opencv-contrib-python`

[opencv-contrib-python](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-contrib-python/)

If you need a non-GUI OpenCV:

`pip install opencv-python-headless`

[opencv-python-headless](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python-headless/)

If you need to install specific version you can use `==` to check the available version first like

`pip install opencv-python==`, then install the version you require